# What is the best Way to copy data across 2 sql instances on different servers and Envirinments

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to optimize my way of copying sql data, from our local environment to our hosted environment.

Every day staff members make changes to a few tables on our local environment and at the end of the day these changes need to get carried across to our hosted environment. There is a lot of data that gets transferred but I only push.

I am current using linked servers and selecting from one table and inserting to another i.e.

```
insert into table a
select * from server.db.dbo.table
where server.db.dbo.table.column in (select column from b)
```

I read up on bulk inserts but that seems to just be a way of inserting from a file to a database. There are multiple tables and I run this under a transaction which locks the tables and stops the site for about 30 minutes.

I am currently looking at storing the data in holding tables and then copying it from there. This is much quicker.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Edit

Please note. I only need to push across some of the records in the tables not all of them.

Comment: For speed, avoid linked servers and write a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package with data flows that transfer the records from a source provider to a destination provider.  SSIS packages take some effort to write, but they are fast.

Comment: That looks like a pull to me.  Is table a on the local or remote server?  That in might not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to synch full database?
Is the target environment R/O?

if the answer to both questions is yes, the simplest thing to do will be `log shipping`, there are tricks to make the target database as available to R/O between log transfers.

If you need just tables and those tables as R/O, I would look for `transactional replication`.

also you can use `SSIS` as @criticalfix suggests

Comment: It's just 4 tables but lots of data but its not all the data in the tables.

Comment: What do you mean by R/O

Comment: with `transactional replication` you can choose what tables and even columns will be replicated, and it will pickup only those changed rows (from each transaction).

Comment: They are read only at the other end (the destination) Also I only push across the records that have been finalized by the user.

Comment: so `transactional replication` would be my choice. no risks of locks at all, since it works with the `transaction log`. it can work for long time while you keep the target R/O. [read more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx)

Comment: yes but that results in the data in the source and target tables being identical. I can only push across the data that has been finalized by the user.